# automatic rewrite URLs .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to clean url for my web site.
The structure is like this :

```
example.com/home
```

inside the home folder I have:

```
index.php 
ambiente.php
.htaccess
```

This is my `.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+ambiente\.php\?ambiente=([^\s&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ ambiente/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ambiente/([^/]+)/?$ ambiente.php?ambiente=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I would like the file did this:

```
example.com/home/ambiente.php?ambiente=living

example.com/home/ambiente/living
```

The problem is that the URLs are not automatically rewritten.

If I click on the `ambiente.php?ambiente=living` link in the index file, in the address bar I find `example.com/home/ambiente.php?ambiente=living`.

If I write in the address bar: `http://example.com/home/ambiente/living`, it  works properly!

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rewritecondition matches `/ambiente.php?ambiente=foobar` but it does not match the orignal uri `/home/ambiente.php?ambiente=foobar` Replace your first rewriteRule with the following

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+home/ambiente\.php\?ambiente=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /home/ambiente/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!